# How to assign the column of one matrix to another, nalgebra?

Tags: math, rust, linear-algebra, nalgebra

I am using nalgebra and I want to modify one matrix by setting it as the columns of another with compatible dimensions, like this:

```rs
    let zero: T = convert(0.0);
    let mut basis = DMatrix::from_element(rows, rank, zero);
    // matrix is an input with dimensions rows x cols
    for i in 0..location.len()
    {
        basis.column_mut(i) = matrix.column(location[i]);
    }
```

I have also tried dereferencing both sides of the assignment and looked for an "assign" method of some kind, no luck.

`set_column` doesn't work because `DMatrix` does not implement `DimName`

My current work around is this, but I don;t like it one bit:

```rs
 // Construct basis vectors initialized to 0.
    let zero: T = convert(0.0);
    let mut basis = DMatrix::from_element(rows, rank, zero);

    for i in 0..location.len()
    {
        // Copy the pivot column from the matrix.
        let col = location[i];
        for r in 0..matrix.nrows()
        {
            basis[(r, i)] = matrix[(r, col)];
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can't imagine `T` is anything but a generic type parameter. That means this isn't a [mre]. Please provide one.

Comment: @cafce25 I can't imagine that it matters whether this is an MRE or not. They're clearly asking about syntax, and they've clearly demonstrated the semantics.

Comment: @mcmuffin6o Well I'm fairly certain I know a way but I won't bother creating a MRE to check it. And I won't post a unverified answer either. Is it strictly necessary? - No. Would it improve the question? - Most definitely. So why not add it?

Comment: @cafce25 If you're not going to bother meeting a student where they're at, someone else will. If it's the quality of the question you're concerned about, go ahead and edit it based off of my answer.

Comment: @cafce25 Strictly speaking, yes, you're correct -- they were so close to an MRE that they might as well have just properly made one. On the other hand, I'm so sick of everyone on this site being insufferable when questions aren't asked with perfect etiquette. In this case, it wasn't much work to tweak their code to be an MRE, especially when they provided an easily understood example of what they wanted, along with an easily understood workaround. They simply wanted to remove the row-by-row tedium of their workaround, and `set_column` does that (if you call it correctly).

Comment: @mcmuffin6o I think you've misunderstood the purpose of this site. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] where it's explained. It's expressly not the purpose to help OP with a question they have.

Comment: @cafce25 "It's expressly not the purpose to help OP with a question they have."
LMAO excuse me for trying to help OP with their question on a Q&A site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what `column_mut` means, what it does, or how it's supposed to work, either. The documentation for it is fairly sparse (nonexistent). I think `set_column` does what you're trying to do (perhaps you called it incorrectly?):

```rust
use nalgebra::DMatrix;
let rows = 2;
let cols = 3;
let zero = 0.0;
let mut basis = DMatrix::from_element(rows, cols, zero);
let matrix = DMatrix::from_row_slice(rows, cols, &[
  1.0, 3.0, 5.0,
  2.0, 4.0, 6.0
]);
let location = [1, 0, 2];
for i in 0..location.len() {
  basis.set_column(i, &matrix.column(location[i]));
}
```

(I tweaked your code to be an MWE)